# Paint Program: Array is writing backwards to the panel

Tags: java

I posted this code earlier, and got a very good answer, but not a working answer. Could someone please show me how to change my code in order to get this fixed? This will run and compile. It is supposed to draw a line on top of a line, but instead it is drawing under the previous line. I have tried using     Collections.reverse(segments); but it doesn't take care of element at zero. I also have tried changing to segments.add(new Segment()); but I am not sure what to change in MouseMotionListener to get this to work accordingly. Any help with this would be great! Thank You! :)

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.geom.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.swing.*;

public class SimplePaint extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
JButton action = new JButton();
JButton red = new JButton();
JButton blue = new JButton();
JButton yellow = new JButton();
Color initial = Color.MAGENTA;
JButton thin = new JButton();
JButton medium = new JButton();
JButton thick = new JButton();
Stroke stroke = new BasicStroke(3);
private static ArrayList<Point> points = new ArrayList<Point>();

JButton erase = new JButton();
JButton drawing = new JButton();
Point start = null;
Point end = null;
Line2D draw = new Line2D.Float();
JPanel panel = new JPanel();

private class Segment {
    private final List<Point> points = new ArrayList<Point>();
    private final Color color = initial;
    private final Stroke stroke = SimplePaint.this.stroke;
}

private final List<Segment> segments = new ArrayList<>();

public SimplePaint() {
    getContentPane().add(panel);
    setSize(450, 450);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    design();

    addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
            segments.add(0, new Segment());
        }
   });

    addMouseMotionListener(new MouseMotionAdapter() {
        public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
            segments.get(0).points.add(e.getPoint());
            repaint();
        }
    });

    addMouseMotionListener(new MouseMotionAdapter(){

        @Override
        public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e){
            points.add(e.getPoint());
            repaint();
        }
    });

    blue.addActionListener(this);
    red.addActionListener(this);
    yellow.addActionListener(this);
    thin.addActionListener(this);
    medium.addActionListener(this);
    thick.addActionListener(this);
    erase.addActionListener(this);
    drawing.addActionListener(this);
}

public void design() {
    panel.setBackground(Color.BLACK);

    blue.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
    blue.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(50, 25));
    panel.add(blue);

    red.setBackground(Color.RED);
    red.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(50, 25));
    panel.add(red);

    yellow.setBackground(Color.yellow);
    yellow.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(50, 25));
    panel.add(yellow);

    thin.setText("Thin");
    panel.add(thin);

    medium.setText("Medium");
    panel.add(medium);

    thick.setText("Thick");
    panel.add(thick);

    erase.setText("Erase");
    panel.add(erase);

    drawing.setText("Draw");
    panel.add(drawing);
}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    if(e.getSource() == blue){
        initial = Color.BLUE;
    }else if(e.getSource() == red){
        initial = Color.RED;
    }else if(e.getSource() == yellow){
        initial = Color.YELLOW;
    }else if(e.getSource() == thin){
        stroke = new BasicStroke(1);
    }else if(e.getSource() == medium){
        stroke = new BasicStroke(5);
    }else if(e.getSource() == thick){
        stroke = new BasicStroke(10);
    }else if(e.getSource() == erase){
        initial = Color.WHITE;
        stroke = new BasicStroke(15);
    }

    //repaint();
}

@Override
public void paint(Graphics g) {
    super.paint(g);
    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;

    int x1, y1, x2, y2;

    for (Segment segment : segments) {
        g2.setColor(segment.color);
        g2.setStroke(segment.stroke);

        for (int p = 0; p < segment.points.size() - 1; p++) {
            x1 = segment.points.get(p).x;
            y1 = segment.points.get(p).y;
            x2 = segment.points.get(p + 1).x;
            y2 = segment.points.get(p + 1).y;
            g2.drawLine(x1, y1, x2, y2);


        }

    }
    g2.dispose();

}  

public static void main(String []args){
    SimplePaint s = new SimplePaint();
    s.setVisible(true);
}
}
```

Comment: What do you recommend to fix this? It would be so great to get an answer for my issue. :)

Comment: I've just looked at what your code does and realised my comment was silly and size() - 1 was intentional. I'll have another look!

Comment: `mousePressed()` --> `segments.add(new Segment());` and `mouseDragged()` --> `segments.get(segments.size() - 1).points.add(e.getPoint());` (i.e. last index rather than 0) fixes the issue for me.

Comment: That works perfectly! Thank you so much! If you would like to post that as an answer I can mark it correct and it will boost your reputation. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix your issue, you need to add to the end of the `List` and not the beginning:

```
addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
        segments.add(new Segment());
    }
});

addMouseMotionListener(new MouseMotionAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
       segments.get(segments.size() - 1).points.add(e.getPoint());
       repaint();
    }
});
```

Additionally, the second `mouseDragged()` implementation appears redundant, if you remove it, it still functions as expected.

```
// Can be removed
addMouseMotionListener(new MouseMotionAdapter() {    
    @Override
    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
        points.add(e.getPoint());
        repaint();
    }
});
```

Also, you should really use a `JComponent` or `JPanel` to paint your sketch, `@Override` `paintComponent()` as opposed to `paint()` with this approach. This will help (or should completely) remove the flickering you see. Coupled with a [`javax.swing.Timer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/Timer.html) to `repaint()` as opposed to dragging which could update extremely (and unnecessarily) quickly.

Finally, you should ensure your GUI is running on the event dispatch thread using [`SwingUtilities.invokeLater(Runnable doRun)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingUtilities.html#invokeLater-java.lang.Runnable-), since [Swing objects are not thread safe](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html).

e.g.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            SimplePaint s = new SimplePaint();
            s.setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}
```